# Video AVAsset — only saves one object to arrays

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use implement photo and video functionality to my iOS app with Swift.

Images work fine. The `images` and `uiimages` arrays are correctly populated.
With video — it only seems to save one video to the array (i.e. it overwrites the existing video, even though the `imageIndex` has changed. This happens in both the `videos` and `media` arrays).

What could be causing this? It seems I have the exact same logic for `videos` as for `images`, and saving images in the `media` (`[AnyObject]`) array works fine, but not for videos.

```swift
@State var images = [Image?](repeating: nil, count: 6)
@State var uiimages = [UIImage?](repeating: nil, count: 6)
@State var videos = [AVAsset?](repeating: nil, count: 6)
@State var media = [AnyObject?](repeating: nil, count: 6)

...

CaptureImageView(isShown: $showCaptureImageView, uiimage: $uiimages[imageIndex], image: $images[imageIndex], video: $videos[imageIndex], amedia: $media[imageIndex], camera: camera)
    .onAppear {
        self.disableButtons = true
    }
    .onDisappear {
        var nonNil:Int = 0
        for media in media {
            if media != nil {
                nonNil += 1
            }
        }
        self.nonNilImages = nonNil
        self.imageIndex = nonNil
        self.disableButtons = false
        print("-------")
        print("imageIndex: \(imageIndex)")
        print(videos)
        print(media)
    }
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CaptureImageView {
    
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var uiimage: UIImage?
    @Binding var image: Image?
    @Binding var video: AVAsset?
    @Binding var amedia: AnyObject?
    
    var camera: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image, uiimage: $uiimage, video: $video, amedia: $amedia)
    }
}
extension CaptureImageView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        if camera {
            
            if let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera) {
                picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
            }
            
            picker.sourceType = .camera
        }
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) {
        
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  @Binding var isCoordinatorShown: Bool
  @Binding var uiimageInCoordinator: UIImage?
  @Binding var imageInCoordinator: Image?
  @Binding var videoInCoordinator: AVAsset?
  @Binding var mediaInCoordinator: AnyObject?
    
  init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>, uiimage: Binding<UIImage?>, video: Binding<AVAsset?>, amedia: Binding<AnyObject?>) {
    _isCoordinatorShown = isShown
    _uiimageInCoordinator = uiimage
    _imageInCoordinator = image
    _videoInCoordinator = video
    _mediaInCoordinator = amedia
  }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
            let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
            print(asset)
            videoInCoordinator = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
            mediaInCoordinator = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
        } else if let unwrapImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            // handle image pick
            uiimageInCoordinator = unwrapImage
            imageInCoordinator = Image(uiImage: unwrapImage)
            mediaInCoordinator = unwrapImage
        }
        isCoordinatorShown = false
    }
  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
     isCoordinatorShown = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Binding is only for SwiftUI views they don’t work in classes or structs that aren’t views. You might get coincidental updates but never something reliable.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I originally found this example code for just Images, and it had @Binding, and worked perfectly every time. What do you suggest I do instead?

Comment: Merge the extension and the capture image view then get rid of all the binding in the class and just reference the parent like Apple does. I think if you look at the SwiftUI tutorial “Interfacing with UIKit” you will find a sample of a Coordinator that references the parent instead of passing all the variables.